# Shouldn't the content of a file remain unaltered if I read it byte-by-byte?

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

Why does the following code alter "öäüß"?  (I am using it to split big files into multiple small ones...)

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
File newFile;
BufferedWriter bw;
newFile = new File(filePathBase + "." + String.valueOf(files.size() + 1) + fileExtension);
files.add(newFile);
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
try {
    byte[] c = new byte[1024];
    int lineCount = 0;
    int readChars = 0;
    while ( ( readChars = is.read(c) ) != -1 )
        for ( int i=0; i<readChars; i++ ) {
            bw.write(c[i]);
            if ( c[i] == '\n' )
                if ( ++lineCount % linesPerFile == 0 ) {
                    bw.close();
                    newFile = new File(filePathBase + "." + String.valueOf(files.size() + 1) + fileExtension);
                    files.add(newFile);
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
                }
        }
} finally {
    bw.close();
    is.close();
}
```

My understanding of character encoding is that everything should remain the same as long as i keep each byte the same.  Why does this code alter bytes?

Thanks a bunch in advance~

====================  SOLUTION  ====================

The mistake is that `FileWriter` interprets bytes and shouldn't be used to just output plain bytes, thanks @meriton and @Jonathan Rosenne.  Just changing everything to `BufferedOutputStream` doesn't do it though, since `BufferedOutputStream` is too slow!  I ended up improving my file split-and-copy code to include a bigger read-array size and only `write()` when necessary ...

```
File newFile = new File(filePathBase + "." + String.valueOf(files.size() + 1) + fileExtension);
files.add(newFile);
InputStream iS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
OutputStream oS = new FileOutputStream(newFile); // BufferedOutputStream wrapper toooo slow!
try {
    byte[] c;
    if ( linesPerFile > 65536 )
        c = new byte[65536];
    else
        c = new byte[1024];
    int lineCount = 0;
    int readChars = 0;
    while ( ( readChars = iS.read(c) ) != -1 ) {
        int from = 0;
        for ( int idx=0; idx<readChars; idx++ )
            if ( c[idx] == '\n' && ++lineCount % linesPerFile == 0 ) {
                oS.write(c, from, idx+1 - from);
                oS.close();
                from = idx+1;
                newFile = new File(filePathBase + "." + String.valueOf(files.size() + 1) + fileExtension);
                files.add(newFile);
                oS = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            }
        oS.write(c, from, readChars - from);
    }
} finally {
    iS.close();
    oS.close();
}
```

Comment: What are the values of the fileExtension variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An InputStream reads bytes, an OutputStream writes them. A Reader reads characters, a Writer writes them.

You read with an InputStream, and write with a FileWriter. That is, you read bytes, but write characters. Specifically,

```
bw.write(c[i]);
```

invokes the method

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException
```

whose [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29) says:

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

That is, the byte is implicitly converted into an int, and then reinterpreted as a unicode code point, which is then written to the file using the platform default encoding (because you don't specify the encoding the FileWriter should use).

Comment: I changed `BufferedWriter` with `FileOutputStream` and it works, great!  The only problem: IT IS SUUUPER SLOW, compared to the `BufferedWriter` implementation.  Is there something fast that just writes bytes without interpreting them in any way?

Comment: The equivalent to a `BufferedWriter` is a `BufferedOutputStream` ... and yes, unbuffered byte-by-byte writing is likely slow ...

Answer (score 1):

You are reading bytes and writing characters. The line bw.write(c[i]); assumes each byte is a character, but in the input file this is not necessarily so, it depends on the encoding that was used. Encodings such as UTF-8 may use 2 or more bytes per character, and you are converting each byte individually. For example, in UTF-8, ö is encoded as 2 bytes, hexadecimal c3 b6. As you process them individually, you may see the first character as Ã.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your `while` condition `( readChars = is.read(c) ) != -1` , because of this it is getting into infinite loop and `bw.close();` is never called and file is still in read mode and if at the same time you are trying to perform some operation file will get corrupt and you will get undesired result.